# Validation went wrong in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an angular app which contains a few validation in template.
When I try to run this application, I get a lot of errors.
My app.component.html looks like the following:

```
     <html>
    <div class="container">
      <p class="jumbotron display-4">Open Account</p>
      <form >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ngModel name="name"  #name="ngModel" maxlength="30" minlength="2" required>
             <div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
        class="alert alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
        First Name is required.
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
        First Name cannot be more than 30 characters long.
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
       First Name must be at least 2 characters long.
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname"
             ngModel name="lname"  #lname="ngModel" maxlength="30" minlength="2" required>
             <div *ngIf="lname.invalid && (lname.dirty || lname.touched)"
        class="alert alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="lname.errors.required">
        Last Name is required.
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="lname.errors.minlength">
        Last Name cannot be more than 30 characters long.
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="lname.errors.minlength">
        Last Name must be at least 2 characters long.
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone"
             ngModel name="phone"  #phone="ngModel" maxlength="10" minlength="10" required>
             <div *ngIf="phone.invalid && (phone.dirty || phone.touched)"
        class="alert alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="phone.errors.required">
        Phone number is required.
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="phone.errors.minlength">
        Phone number must be of 10 digits long.
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="address">Address</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address"
             ngModel name="address"  #address="ngModel" minlength="2" required>
             <div *ngIf="address.invalid && (address.dirty || address.touched)"
        class="alert alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="address.errors.required">
       Address is required.
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="address.errors.minlength">
        Address length must be at least 2 characters long.
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="address">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city"
             ngModel name="city"  #city="ngModel" required>
             <div *ngIf="city.invalid && (city.dirty || city.touched)"
        class="alert alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="city.errors.required">
       City field is required.
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="address">State</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state"
             ngModel name="state"  #state="ngModel" required>
             <div *ngIf="state.invalid && (state.dirty || state.touched)"
        class="alert alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="state.errors.required">
       State field is required.
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-25 mx-auto d-block">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </html>
```

My browser shows the these errors:

`cannot Get/`
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

[![faild][1]][1]

In my console I see the following errors:

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:11:27 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

11   <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
                             ~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:14:27 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

14   <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
                             ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:17:27 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

17   <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
                             ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:29:28 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

29   <div *ngIf="lname.errors.required">
                              ~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:32:28 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

32   <div *ngIf="lname.errors.minlength">
                              ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:35:28 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

35   <div *ngIf="lname.errors.minlength">
                              ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:47:28 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

47   <div *ngIf="phone.errors.required">
                              ~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:50:28 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

50   <div *ngIf="phone.errors.minlength">
                              ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


[91mError: src/app/app.component.html:62:30 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

62   <div *ngIf="address.errors.required">
                                ~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:65:30 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

65   <div *ngIf="address.errors.minlength">
                                ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:77:27 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

77   <div *ngIf="city.errors.required">
                             ~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5m   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.


Error: src/app/app.component.html:89:28 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

89   <div *ngIf="state.errors.required">
                              ~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

---

app.component.ts:-

```
import { Component,ViewChild,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'val';
}
```

--------------------------x----------------------------------x-------------------

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Validate</title>
  <base href="./">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have tried to access name.errors.required and etc.. but probably is null as you can see in the error message `Object is possibly 'null'.`

Comment: Can you show the `app.component.ts`?

Comment: I am just guessing because you have an `app.component.html`, presumably you had written something in `app.component.ts` file as well.

Comment: I am executing same set of code on differrent machine it is working fine but  i don't know why it is not working in my machine

Comment: So where does `name` come from? Which ts?

Comment: name is the variable name for the input textfield similarly you can see i had use lname and phone no

Comment: Can you show the index.html pls?

Answer (score 0):

In your index html you have to see a `<base>` tag.
Change `<base href="/"> to <base href="./">`

Comment: What does it show your browser console->network tab?

Comment: As per question in network tab it is showing just files like localhost,runtime.js , polyfills.js and etc

Comment: i am able to solve this issue by just adding "?" ...................*ngIf="name.errors.required to *ngIf="name.errors?.required

Answer (score 0):

i am able to solve this issue by just adding "?" ,

*ngIf="name.errors.required to *ngIf="name.errors?.required